# Gradually increment CSS opacity on scroll down with Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to darken my div container with background-color with rgba values and increase the alpha value gradually as the user scrolls down the page. So by the time he scrolls down about 500 pixels, the alpha value reaches 1 = completely dark. How can i achieve this using jquery or javascript?

I've tried all i can but i can  only get it to darken in increments of say every 100px but i want it to be a constant smooth opacity transition from 0px to 500px scroll down.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: ive only tried breakpoints so every 100px scroll i added a statement to increase the opacity by 0.1 but id need 10 breakpoints and its not smooth, so that doesn't work

Comment: actually it has nothing to do with the scroll then :)

Answer (score 0):

Read about `$(document).on("scroll");`
If you have never been using `events` then I advise to read about `events` first. With making scroll more smoooth I guess its more tricky.

Good luck :)

Comment: i'm aware of how scroll event works perfectly. I'm trying to achieve the smoothness only

Comment: I see. I think the breakpoints are not really needed. Why don't you calculate opacity based on scroll position only ? If you would add some code, people would be able to help more.